# set value to textbox in grid with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, grid

I have a textbox in my grid -> RadTextBoxSandi

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gridlist" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" Width="100%"  PageSize="50" AllowPaging="true" 
                 OnPageIndexChanged="gridlist_PageIndexChanged" OnItemDataBound="gridlist_OnItemDataBound">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID_DANA_MASUK" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true">
        <NoRecordsTemplate>
            Data tidak ada...
        </NoRecordsTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="DANA MASUK">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ButSelect" name="ButSelect" value="Check All" onclick="CheckAll()">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItemSelect" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="ID DANA MASUK">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LBLIDDANAMASUK" Text='<%# Bind("ID_DANA_MASUK") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="REFERENCE NUMBER">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LBLREFERENCE_NUMBER" Text='<%# Bind("REFERENCE_NUMBER") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TGL_TRANSAKSI" HeaderText="TGL TRANSAKSI"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NAMA_PEMILIK" HeaderText="NAMA PEMILIK"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NO_REK" HeaderText="NO REK"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="VALUTA_TRANSFER" HeaderText="VALUTA TRANSFER"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NOMINAL_TRANSFER" HeaderText="NOMINAL TRANSFER"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="VALUTA_DITERIMA" HeaderText="VALUTA DITERIMA"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NOMINAL_DITERIMA" HeaderText="NOMINAL DITERIMA"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NAMA_PENGIRIM" HeaderText="NAMA PENGIRIM"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NAMA_BANK_PENGIRIM" HeaderText="NAMA BANK PENGIRIM"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BERITA" HeaderText="BERITA"/>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="PEMBAYARAN">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LBLPEMBAYARAN" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="SANDI KETERANGAN">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBoxSandi" runat="server" onclick="openWin();
                            return false;"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and i want to set value that textbox from my radwindow argument when it closed

```
function OnClientClose(oWnd, args) {
    var arg = args.get_argument();
            var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gridlist.ClientID %>");
            if (arg) {
    // grid.textContent =  arg.Kode;
}
```

so, how to set that RadTextBoxSandi in gridlist with javascript?

**UPDATE**:

```
 function FindElement() { 
var grid = $find("<%=gridlist.ClientID %>"); 
var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView(); 
var length = MasterTable.get_dataItems().length; 
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
 var RadTextBoxSandi = MasterTable.get_dataItems()[i].findElement("RadTextBoxSandi");//access the TextBox control 
RadTextBoxSandi.innerText = "Test";// assigning value to TextBox control }
 }
```

**BUT**

it make all my textbox filled the same value, anyone know how to set the value to the selected textbox?

Comment: just post the rendered html output

Comment: To clarify @ChamikaSandamal's comment... If this is a JavaScript question, the ASP code is irrelevant and not very useful (if at all).

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be a bit dirty, by watch the generate id of RadTextBoxSandi using Firebug (if you use Firefox) or press F12 if you are using IE8 or higher. Then you can access the object using

```
document.getElementById("gridlist_RadTextBoxSandi")
```

Something like that, but myself is not prefer to do that, I'd rather to find another way by manipulate user interface to avoid this dirty approach